# When converted string date into date time it give me null

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

[image]
date get from api and show in console with out converted date it's show perfect but when try to convert in date time it give me null

```
// Range Date
          debugPrint('::::::::::::::::::Dates Range:::::::::::::::::::');
          startRangeDate = menstrualCycleData!.periodDays!.first;
          debugPrint('**********Start Range = startRangeDate*****************');
          debugPrint('**********Start Range converted into datetime = ${DateTime.tryParse(startRangeDate)}*****************');
          endRangeDate = menstrualCycleData!.periodDays!.last;
          debugPrint('**********End Range = $endRangeDate*****************');
          debugPrint('**********End Range converted into datetime = ${DateTime.tryParse(endRangeDate)}*****************');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime like this.

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat("//Your prefer dateFormat - dd MM yyyy");
print (format.parse(endRangeDate));
```

To know more about available dateFormat checkout [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html).